# C# linq to sql access app.config file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, app-config

I am having a linq to sql problem with a C# 2010 windows form application when it is changed to a dll and accessed by other applications. The purpose of the calling the code as a dll is for performance reasons and to share the code accross multiple applications.

When the application is on its own, it runs fine.

Basically when the linq to sql was dragged to the desktop, a default linq to sql connection was setup by the .net framework. However I changed the *.designer.cs  to use the system.configuration namespace,
added a reference to the system.configuration namespace, and changed the default linq to sql connection to use the database connection obttained in app.config file. I also removed any refernces to the default database connections in the the 'properties or 'settings' section for each project file folder.

Now the problem is the default setting values to the database are reset by the .net framework. Thwe values in the app.config file are no longer being used.

Can you show me code, point me to a reference, and/or tell how I can make this application is the connection string values in the app.config file again?

Answer (score 1):

A dll is run in the the context of the application calling it.  It is not an application in its own right, so giving it an app.config file is useless.  The configuration settings used by the dll are supplied by the calling application's .config file (it can be an app.config file or a web.config file).  In your case, any application using the dll must have the database connection defined its own .config file.

Comment: The application calling the dll has its own app.config fie. But the calling application is not passing its values to the dll that is being called. Is there a way the calling program can pass the config file settings to the dll? If so, can you show me code and/orpoint me to code that will show me how to pass the database connections to the dll?

Comment: This is how it is designed to work.  Is the app.config being renamed to the application's name and copied to the bin directory?

Comment: Here is what is what occuring currently: 1. the calling program has its own app.config that that config file stays in its original location. 2. The program that is being called has 4 app config files and those app.config files stay in their original location. Each project project file (4 total) for the solution has one app.config file. 3. Are you saving I should rename each of the 4 app.config files and place them into the bin directory for where the dll is being accessed? Can you give me more directions?

Comment: In order for a configuration file to read it: a) needs to be in the bin directory where the exe and dll reside and b) needs be named with same name as the exe + .config.  So if your app is called someapp.exe, the config file should be named someapp.exe.config. If this is not happening automatically, add a post build event that copies and renames the app.config appropriately.

Comment: Can you show me some code for the postbuild event that will rename each of the 4 app.config files? How will my main program that does the calling know what app.config file to use? In the C# code, can you show me code on how the calling program will access the appropriate app.config file that it needs?

Comment: A program can only have one config file. If you need to switch the configuration dynamically at run time, it can be be done, but not through the basic configuration.  My understanding was you have four applications using the same dll, so each would have its own app.config.

Comment: There is one application currently using the dll. The dll is setup with a solution file with 4 project files. Each project file has its own app.config file. Since I want to reference a specific config file at run time from the main application, can you tell me how to reference the config file in a spcific project file?

Comment: Are these other projects dlls?